# Protocols For Informatica Architecture

Tags: network-protocols, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, informatica-powercenter, informatica

Before I can gain VPN access to run Informatica from home, I need to identify all the protocols Informatica uses for an ETL job to run. I found that it uses a native protocol for the repository, source, and target databases (so sqlnet for Oracle). I also know that I'll need to identify all protocols that could potentially be used to extract data from non-RDBMS sources (such as ftp).

But, what protocol would be used to connect to the server to run the job? Are there any other protocols I'd need to be aware of that it might use as part of the whole process of opening up Designer, creating a job, and running it?

Comment: I know nothing about Informatica, but why would you need to open up ports over the VPN? Are you really going to transfer data between the office and your home as part of an ETL job? I think a more usual approach would be to connect to a server at work using RDP or SSH, and use whatever tools are installed on the server to start jobs or work with the repository. So the only question is how to get remote shell/desktop access over the VPN, at least that's how it would work in most environments I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the understanding shared by @Pondlife in the comment.
If you are going to access Informatica through vpn, you need not worry about anything on protocols side.  With VPN,you actually join the local network of the server and therefore no need of any configuration on the vpn itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Informatica architecture is a client/server architecture.

You will need to configure the powercenter client to connect to the server!

The protocol used is TCP/IP. The powercenter client uses a hostname and a port number to connect the powercenter client to the server. You will need the IP address of the server and the port number to connect it on.